# How to use In Filter feature for RelationShipFilter

Tags: 2sxc

I have a relationship filter with [In:Filter:Name] option, but Filter have an array with more than 1 result. Filter is working just with first result of array.

RelationshipFilter should work with any of the results for In results array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't supported yet, sorry. You'll have to use LINQ in your template for now.